# Coherent state path integral for Hamiltonian with anomalous terms (

Tags: path-integral, superconductivity, many-body

I know little about path integrals from Altland and Simons. When they do superconductivity with the path integral formalism they start by writing down the action with a local interaction, do the Hubbard-Stratonovich decoupling and then arrive at a partition function:
$$\mathcal{Z} = \int \mathcal{D}(\bar{\psi},\psi)\int \mathcal{D}(\bar{\Delta},\Delta)e^{-\int \left(\frac{|\Delta|^2}{g}-\bar{\Psi}G^{-1}\Psi\right)d\tau d^dr},$$
where the spinors are $\bar{\Psi}(\mathbf{r})=(\bar\psi_{\uparrow}(\mathbf{r}),\psi_{\downarrow}(\mathbf{r}))$ and the measure $\mathcal{D}(\bar{\psi},\psi)=\prod_{r,\sigma}d\bar\psi_{\sigma}(\mathbf{r})d\psi_{\sigma}(\mathbf{r})$.

Now integrating out the fermions by doing the integral over the Grasmann fields in this Nambu form is fine I think as it is diagonal in $\mathbf{r}$ so I can solve the path integral for each $\mathbf{r}$, diagonalise $G^{-1}$ in Nambu spinor space and get the result as $\prod_r \text{det}(G^{-1})$ with the determinant over Nambu spinor space. This then becomes $e^{\int d^dr  \text{ln}(\text{det}(G^{-1}))}$ when re-exponentiating. That is how far I understand this.

Lets say I now wanted to work with a system that had a pairing action with anomalous terms that was not local in space, like a spinless Kitaev chain that would have something like $\Delta c^{\dagger}_{r+1}c^{\dagger}_{r} + h.c$. I could then imagine getting an integral like:

$$\int \mathcal{D}(\bar{\psi},\psi)e^{-\sum_{\alpha ,\beta}\left\{\bar\psi_\alpha G_{\alpha,\beta}\psi_\beta + \bar\psi_\alpha \bar{A}_{\alpha,\beta}\bar{\psi}_\beta+\psi_\alpha A_{\alpha,\beta}{\psi}_\beta\right\}},$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are just some quantum numbers and the $\psi$ are still Grassmann numbers. This is now more difficult due to the anomalous terms I am unsure how to go at it. I tried writing it in terms of Nambu spinors $\bar\xi=(\bar\psi_1,...,\bar\psi_N,\psi_1,...,\psi_N)$ and $\xi=(\psi_1,...,\psi_N,\bar\psi_1,...,\bar\psi_N)^T$. I can write it quadratically in terms of the spinors with a metrix, $M$, having blocks of $A,\bar{A}$ and $G$. I then try the approach of diagonalising the product in the exponent $\bar\xi M\xi $ with a unitary operator and rewriting the measure in terms of the new eigenvectors of $M$, but I just can't get it all the way as I can't quite get it in a form of $2N$ independent gaussian integrals.

I hope that someone has done these calculations and could hopefully help me in how to understand and work out these types of Gaussian integrals!